# Adding images on either side of a complex title

Tags: graphics, xetex, header-footer

I have been trying to figure this out for hours. I want to add 2 images to the top of my resume on either side of my name and info. Right now my header on my resume looks like this:
[image: resume header w/o graphic]

```
\documentclass[]{deedy-resume-openfont}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\namesection {Graeme}{Woods}{
\begin{multicols}{2}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\begin{normalsize}
\begin{flushright}
city, state \\
(xxx) xxx - xxxx \\
email@gmail.com \\
\columnbreak
\end{flushright}
\begin{flushleft}
website.com \\
github.com/username \\
linkedin.com/in/username
\end{flushleft}
\end{normalsize}
\end{multicols}
}
\end{document}
```

I want to add 2 graphics on either side of my name and info. The closest I've gotten to what I want is:
[[image: resume header w/ graphic]

```
\documentclass[]{deedy-resume-openfont}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{calc}


\begin{document}


\noindent\begin{minipage}[t][4.0cm][t]{\textwidth}
\centering
\namesection{First}{Last}{
\begin{tabular}{p{0.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}p{0.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|p{0.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}p{0.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}
\includegraphics[width=3.25cm]{pics/left.png}

& \makecell[br]{
city, state \\
(xxx) xxx - xxxx \\
thisismyemail@gmail.com
}
& \makecell[bl]{
website123.com \\
github.com/username \\
linkedin.com/in/username123
  }
& \makecell[br]{\includegraphics[width=3.25cm]{pics/right.png}}
\end{tabular}
}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

But it is taking up too much vertical space. Since this is for a resume I need it to be more compact. I would like to move the contact info up to the top of the column separator and then short the separator. The full project is [here](https://www.overleaf.com/13525740krbfssvrztyt) if you would like to check out the class I am using. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm pretty new to LaTeX and a lot of the specifics comes from a .cls file should I attach that as well? I'm having trouble recreating my design without the .cls file.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I linked the full project and got the code snippets a little closer to compilable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some visual formatting:

```
\documentclass[]{deedy-resume-openfont}
\usepackage{makecell,calc}

\begin{document}


\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t][4.0cm][t]{\textwidth}
\vspace{0pt}
\raisebox{-0.5\height+0.35cm}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\includegraphics[width=3.25cm]{pics/left.png}}}%
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering
\namesection{First}{Last}{%
  \begin{tabular}{
    @{}
    p{0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-0.5\arrayrulewidth}
    |
    p{0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-0.5\arrayrulewidth}
    @{}
  }
  \makecell[br]{
    city, state \\
    (xxx) xxx - xxxx \\
    thisismyemail@gmail.com
  }
  &
  \makecell[bl]{
    website123.com \\
    github.com/username \\
    linkedin.com/in/username123
  }
  \end{tabular}%
}
\end{minipage}%
\raisebox{-0.5\height+0.35cm}{\makebox[0pt][r]{\includegraphics[width=3.25cm]{pics/right.png}}}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is excellent! The only thing that would make it perfect was if I could move the graphics down, just a bit, to centre it between the horizontal line and the top of the page. Anything I can do in the `\sbox` ?

Comment: @Graeme Now it's clearer. See the new version. Adjust the amount of raising to suit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try using a table to arrange the images and info (untested):

```
\documentclass[]{deedy-resume-openfont}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{calc}


\begin{document}
\namesection{First}{Last}{
\begin{tabular}{p{0.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}p{0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|p{0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}p{0.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image} & \makecell[br]{city, state \\ (xxx) xxx - xxxx \\ email@gmail.com \\} & \makecell[bl]{website.com \\ github.com/username \\ linkedin.com/in/username} & \makecell[br]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}}
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That definitely makes it closer to what I want Thank you! Now i just need to crunch the table so it takes up less vertical space. I updated my question to match